# How to run example Android code

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm going through some of the Android tutorials and am having trouble running on of the example projects.  [This page](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) explains how to put ads in a project and it links to an example project (http://dl.google.com/googleadmobadssdk/examples/android-banner-essentials.zip).  I downloaded the project, but I don't know how to run it.  I tried "Import" in Eclipse, but I couldn't find any way to do it.  I also tried making a new project, then deleting all the files and replacing them with the files from the example, but then it says "Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/AndroidBannerXML/AndroidManifest.xml'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to right click on project and refresh to sync files

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse :

From the Eclipse menu, click File > New > Project...

From the Select a wizard window, select Android > Android Project from Existing Code, click Next.

From the Import Projets window, set Root directory to where the samples are (normally  C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\samples\android-17\ ); check Copy projects into workspace; click Finish.

The sample application will appear as a project in the Package Explorer.

Run the package as you would any Android project (Run > Run As, ...).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, in Eclipse, click

File

New

Project

select Android Project

Then check the radio button labeled "Create Project from Existing Source"

Then just browse to the project. It will fill in most of the data needed like API level.

PS: For a good tutorial on adding adds, see the link, there is about 6 videos elling you how to add admob and publish your app.

http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston#p/search/0/8IerupLaakE.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don’t install any ADB Driver  then you need to download it first from the link here : click here:
   http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows
2. Install the driver in you windows.
3. Now you open your android code and right click on the project you have made or create a new project and make a program that you want to run. I have already made a  SilentToggleMode code. Just right click and go to Run As > Run Configurations.
4. Then you can see a configuration window. You need to expand Android Application > SilentToggleMode.  On the right, you go to Target and enable by click Always prompt to pick a device.
5. After that click Apply from the bottom of the window.  Now you can click Run from the window bottom or close the window and click Run from the eclipse menu bar and choose your application. Then you can see a window from which you can choose your android device, you select it and click OK.
6. You will be happy now to see that your program is running in your device.

**For details, Please follow the link below:**
[Run Android Program on Android Device](http://masudshrabon.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-program-runs-on-android-device-mobile/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231).